How to prevent link from open in a new tab?
I embedded my Looker Studio dashboard to my website using iframe. On my Dashboard, I have several links, that linked to other Looker Studio Reports. How do I preserve the iframe (Parent frame URL) and prevent links from opening in a new browser tab?
